# How to find the cause of a 100% CPU usage on an iPhone App

Tags: ios, performance, monitoring, instruments

I've diagnosed a strange behavior in an app : after 10 minutes or so, the CPU usage goes to 100%. There's no leak in the app, and it happens while the app is doing nothing.

I can profile this with instruments using the "Time Profiler", but is there a way to find what the actual cause is ?

Comment: Is this on the device or in the simulator?

Comment: I reproduced the bug on the simulator, but apparently it also happens on device.

Comment: When profiling with Instruments (Time Profiler), look to see what method is using the majority of CPU time. Trace the calls back to see why.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When profiling with Instruments (Time Profiler), look to see what method is using the majority of CPU time. Trace the calls back to see why.

Comment: Your response help me for all my applications. TKVM Stuart