# Discarding message for event 0 because of too many unprocessed messages in Xcode 8

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

Whenever the “discarding message” log comes, my app becomes unresponsive. It doesn’t crash, but doesn’t respond to touches either. As if all touch handling stops
after my app goes to back ground , and 2~3 min later when my app goes to fore ground and touch menu , there is no response, and then few min later it dose work

Comment: Did you get any solution for it?

Comment: These messages are coming from Core Location framework. This implies that the CLLocationManager wasn't created on the main thread. [Check this  link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857323/ios5-what-does-discarding-message-for-event-0-because-of-too-many-unprocessed-m/8108274#8108274)

Comment: Is it not related to app unresponsive?

Comment: Yes. When it goes into background mode after sometime app will be unresponsive.

Answer (score 3):

These messages are coming from Core Location framework. This implies that the CLLocationManager wasn't created on the main thread.

**Is it related to app unresponsive?**

Yes. When it goes into background mode after sometime app will be unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing exactly the same behavior. This is what I noticed some time after I arrived here.

My first guess was a memory leak or maybe some missing thread but
I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388453/how-to-find-the-cause-of-a-100-cpu-usage-on-an-iphone-app) to notice that my CPU was blowing up.

Then I tracked the method that was using all the CPU, in my case It was a validation on a `UITextField` via regex. After some research I realized that I was having a [catastrophic backtrack](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). I improved my regex and everything goes well.

I hope this answer would help anyone that arrive here.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the log message was

```
[Client] Discarding message for event 23 because of too many unprocessed messages
```

I find that it happens when I enable a certain breakpoint which outputs the current progress of an NSURLSession download task

When I disable it, the  UI starts to respond again. I haven't found the root cause for this though

Comment: any solution for above?, I am facing similar issue while download video.

Comment: No. I did not work on that much after I found the cause. :)

Answer (score 0):

Discarding message for event 0 because of too many unprocessed messages. 
it was only causing problem in simulator working fine in real device.